# WordPress sub-domain under construction

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I am running `WordPress 3.3.2` with `multisite` in `sub-domain` mode.

I want to add a new `sub-domain` but have it be "offline" until I finish working on it. Is there an easy way to do this?

I know that if its a single site I can just add an `if` in the header file and the site will be online only to me, but in this case all of my sites are using the theme, making it the same header file thus making this solution invalid.

Thank you.

Comment: This is cross-posted to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57770/turn-single-domain-off , so I'm closing this version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the current blog id in the theme like:

```
<?php if (get_current_blog_id() == 1): ?>
  <?php //do stuff ?>
  <?php return ?>
<?php endif ?>
```